# Method of using raw sockets

Tags: c, sockets, networking, raw-sockets

I am using raw sockets for the first time, so excuse me if my question exhibits serious lack of knowledge in this field.
My goal is to make a client-server program using raw sockets where client can send a string to server and server can send a reply. My codes are as follows:

```
/* server.c */
#include "../cn.h"
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 253);
    if (sfd < 0) {
        perror("Could not create socket");
        exit(0);
    }
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Could not bind");
    }
    int nsfd = accept(sfd, NULL, NULL);
    if (nsfd < 0) {
        perror("Could not accept");
        exit(0);
    }
    char buffer[20];
    int sz;
    while (1) {
        if ((sz = read(nsfd, buffer, 20)) < 0) {
            perror("Could not read");
        } else {
            buffer[sz] = '\0';
            strcat(buffer, " form server");
            if (write(nsfd, buffer, strlen(buffer)) < 0) {
                perror("Could not send");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Client code:

```
#include "../cn.h"
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 253);
    if (sfd < 0) {
        perror("Could not create socket");
        exit(0);
    }
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    if (connect(sfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Could not connect");
        exit(0);
    }
    char buffer[20];
    int sz;
    while (1) {
        scanf("%[^\n]s", buffer);
        while (getchar() != '\n')
            ;
        if (write(sfd, buffer, strlen(buffer)) < 0) {
            perror("Could not write");
        } else
        if ((sz = read(sfd,buffer, 20)) < 0) {
            perror("Could not read");
        } else {
            buffer[sz] = '\0';
            printf("Reading: %s\n", buffer);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I am trying to run the programs , it is showing error at the very time of socket creation itself:

```
Could not create socket: Operation not permitted
```

My questions are:

1. What am I missing in this case? Why does is this operation not permitted?
2. Though it is a broad question but, how to use raw sockets with custom protocol ID?
3. Is there any good material available for use of raw sockets with custom protocol?

Comment: Are you root? "Only processes with an effective user ID of 0 or the CAP_NET_RAW capability are allowed to open raw sockets." from https://linux.die.net/man/7/raw

Comment: @user6556709 okk ..running it using sudo solved the problem of creation. But now it is saying accepting is not supported. So, I tried to use sendto() and recvfrom() functions. Now another problem is coming. Whenever I am sending any string from Client side, Server is reading a random string ( an capital E in this case) infinite times! Please put some light on it.

Comment: You can't bind or accept on a raw socket. But you have to use ioctl to set the IP_HDRINCL option. And when reading you receive the full IP frame including the full IP-header. As described on https://linux.die.net/man/7/raw